# Об отношении слов к одному из однородных перечислений

Tags: синтаксис

> *А так же обязаны своевременно уничтожать сорную растительность, карантинные, опасные, и особо опасные сорняки до их цветения и
>   созревания семян.*

Относятся ли слова *цветения, созревания* ко всем перечислениям либо только к последнему? Стилистика предложения сохранена без изменений.

Answer (score 2):

По определению, сорные растения, или сорняки (от «сор») — дикорастущие растения, обитающие на землях, используемых в качестве сельскохозяйственных угодий. Поэтому **можно предположить**, что сорная растительность (сорные растения) ― это обобщающее слово.

**Тогда возможно такое оформление:**

А также обязаны своевременно уничтожать сорную растительность ― карантинные, опасные и особо опасные сорняки ― до их цветения и созревания семян.

Comment: _Sibylla: ...опасные, и особо опасные сорняки_ === А запятая зачем?

Comment: Спасибо,  slava, не нужна запятая, случайно ее скопировала.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки вам уже поправили, не уточнив, впрочем, насколько правомерно. Да и на на вопрос до конца не ответили.

Попробую заполнить.

> А также обязаны своевременно уничтожать сорную растительность,
>   карантинные, опасные и особо опасные сорняки до их цветения и
>   созревания семян.

А вопрос-то непростой. 
Императивного руководства по разрешению двусмысленности тут нет. Формально уточнение "до их цветения" может относится и к последнему, и ко всем, и даже только к двум (а то и трем) последим членам перечисления. Но в последнем случае всё-таки обычно додумываются до какого-то пояснения в формулировке (оба, все три и т. д.). Исходя из этого можно было бы допустить (нестрого), что здесь идет речь о последнем члене - пока не вдаваясь в смысл. 
Но сразу возникает вопрос, а что считать "последним членом"? "Особо опасные" или "опасные и особо опасные"? Разумного решения нет.

Мог бы помочь контекст, если бы стало понятно, почему именно период цветения выбран как некий знаковый рубеж . Но его, контекста, тоже нет.

Остаётся здравый смысл. А он говорит, что резона отделять особо опасные от опасных в плане сроков цветения нет никакого. Таким образом, исходя из логики фразы, заключаем что "сорняки до их цветения и созревания семян" должно относится ко всему перечислению.

Теперь о том, перечисление ли это и если да, то какое. Здесь Sibylla права. Первый член, очевидно, - обобщающий, остальные его раскрывают. 
С учетом предыдущего логического вывода пунктуация ***А также обязаны своевременно уничтожать сорную растительность ― карантинные, опасные и особо опасные сорняки ― до их цветения и созревания семян*** вполне приемлема, а в первоисточнике - не только пунктуационная, но ли логическая ошибка. Но это другой вопрос, все рано надо трактовать так, что слова "цветения, созревания" ко всем членам перечисления.

Может считать, что я просто соединил два данных ранее ответа, хотя реально ситуация тут глубже, чем просто объединение двух соображений.

//---

Я старательно избегал высказывать недоумения по поводу "карантинных" и прочих сорняков. Но все-таки решил высказаться. Сорняки - они и есть сорняки. Ни на какие "опасные", тем более "карантинные", не делятся. Зато любому биологу/агроному/ветеринару известно о существовании *карантинных, опасных и особо опасных **заболеваний***. Именно так и - обычно - именно в таком порядке, даже перечень (типа ГОСТа) есть. Если подобная путаница действительно имеет место в авторском тексте, то ваш вопрос об осмыслении, что там к чему относится, теряет всякую актуальность. Пусть автор скажет, что у него там с чем не срослось.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что у вас две ошибки - орфографическая и пунктуационная.

> А **также** обязаны своевременно уничтожать сорную растительность,
>   карантинные, опасные **[]** и особо опасные сорняки до их цветения и
>   созревания семян.

Формально, т.е. грамматически слова *до их цветения и созревания семян* должны относиться только к сорнякам: карантинным, опасным и особо опасным. А к сорной растительности - нет.

Правда, неясно, что это меняет. Сорняки уничтожаем **до** цветения и созревания, а сорную растительность - можно и **после**? По смыслу это явно не так, и здравый смысл здесь должен победить.

Comment: "Формально" как раз таки только к "особо опасным" ))))